# Fractal fundamentals

Tags: functions, recursion, fractals, cantor-set

I am a programmer by trade, and am very interested in fractals.

To be very basic about the concept, one might say a 'circle of circles' is a fractal. Where each circle is made up of circles, and those circles are made of smaller circles and so on.

This idea is similar to a Sierpinski triangle, which I interpret basically a triangle of triangles.

To test my understanding, I decided to draw out this notion of a 'circle of circles'. Realize, I did this by hand with MS paint, copy and paste. I really should have just written out a simple program using some derivative of pi to get a perfect, mathematical display.

In any case, this image is just to illustrate the concept.

[image]

It's obviously not perfect, my question is: Is the notion of a 'circle of circles', 'triangle of triangles', or 'function of functions' truly the definition of a fractal? And, consequently, is the application of this notion, in this image, a fractal? (I realize it isn't because the alignment is incorrect.)

Note: The coloring was just so I could see the pattern easier, lets assume there is no color. Though if the color had been also repeating, would this still prove true?

I included another, expanding on the use of color:

[image]

Comment: I quite like the picture you've generated :P

Comment: The inside of the entire circle should technically be purple ;)

Comment: Or one of the colors actually, depending on which part of the sequence it is zoomed to.

Comment: Haha agreed, if you're happy with my answer, could you please consider accepting it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Your set is the attractor of an [iterated function system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system), close to one that generates a 9 fold polygasket. Have a look at this [poly-gasket visualization](http://marksmath.org/visualization/gaskets/). Set the number of sides to 9 and the scaling ratio to 0.25. You will generate an image very close to yours.

Comment: Can you write a program to generate it?

Comment: @user48672 It wouldn't be that hard. With a basic, 2d graphics library, you would just need to cycle through a color array, or use a function. For the shape, you would just have to divide 360 degrees by the size of the circles you want, then add them by the division value. So, say 1 circle every 15 degrees. Then you just have to write the algorithm into a recursive function.

Comment: And make sure all the numbers scale properly, mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fractal is just a simple rule that you repeat over and over again. You'd be right to say that it is recursive sometimes, but it isn't always generated recursively, indeed many fractals would be impossible to generate with a recursive "seed" so to speak.

## Mandelbrot Set

For example, here is the mandelbrot set:

[image: Mandelbrot Set]

You can generate this picture by making a grid on your computer to represent the complex plane, and assigning a single complex number to each grid cell (for example, the origin would be 0+0i and the right-most point would be 1+0i).

After this, you can just run this simple mathematical function say, 50 times (arbitrary choice):

$$z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c $$

Where c is a constant of your choosing. If after these 50 iterations, the number you've generated is greater than 2; you've "diverged", so you color that pixel white. Else, you've converged, and you color that pixel white. *you'd want $|c| < 1$ for that reason.

You can generated a colored mandelbrot set by coloring the pixel based on the magnitude after 50 iterations.

## Your Fractal

Your fractal is certainly a fractal if you continue to iterate it. In fact, to make this fractal, you'd just have a function that you will repeat over and over again, however; the manner in which you generate the fractal may be different. I'd therefore say that a good definition for a fractal is just an object that displays self similarity at different scales, or an object that is produced by repeated applications of a simple rule (which is exactly what you've done).

This extends fractals from the realm of graphics and the physical world into other areas where they may someday find an application :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought to be a fractal, the pattern had to the same at every scale. Does the mandelbrot do that? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Yes the mandelbrot set definitely does do that :P [check this out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PD2XgQOyCCk)

Comment: Oh man, that's really trippy haha.

Comment: So what makes the 'circle of circles' different from the mandelbrot set?

Comment: Is the mandelbrot not perfectly recursive? Why/why not?

Comment: I think you possibly could generate the mandelbrot set with a perfectly recursive definition, I just haven't seen it in action before. These zoom graphs are typically generated by using the method I described to you in my answer :) The circle of circles is just an emergent property as far as I understand, it's the result of repetition.

Comment: Well that's somethiing we need to figure out! ;D

Comment: another question, perhaps.

Comment: @user2662833 I don't agree with your first sentence "A fractal is just a simple rule that you repeat over and over again": The sequence $u_{n+1}=u_{n}+1$ with $u_0=0$ corresponds to this definition and generates the integers that are by no means a fractal set...

Comment: Well, I did clarify that it displays self similarity at different scales. I definitely don't intend that first sentence as a definition. I'm just trying to give the OP a feel for what a fractal is.

Comment: The Mandelbrot set does not display self-similarity. On the contrary, you can actually tell where you are in the Mandelbrot set by observing the local structure. This behavior is described nicely in [this paper](http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/papers/prague.pdf) by Bob Devaney. On page 3, he calls the Mandelbrot set "the antithesis of a fractal" because of this.